# How much JVM memory is allocated to an object of XSSFWorkbook?

Tags: java, excel, jvm, xssf

Sorry, I am a bit new to code development, and this may be a really nonsensical question, but I was just curious to know how much JVM memory is allocated to an object of `XSSFWorkbook`.

I am developing a JSP-Servlet based application for which I am using excel sheets for input.

For a single user, the application works fine, but for multiple users, getting

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

The Java heap space was resolved by setting the Xmx parameter minimum to -`Xmx512m` though, but I wanted to optimize my code so that the application can be run using even lesser JVM memory space.

I read that for optimal code Apache POI Streaming, SAX- `SXSSFWorkbook` should be used, but I am not in the position to change the excel code.

Does Garbage Collection work if the object of `XSSFWorkbook` is closed?

Comment: Of course, that depends on the actual document you are processing, but the general tendency for `XSSFWorkbook` is *lots of them*. We encountered documents that would have consumed several GiB, if we allowed it. So sorry, but it’s possible that not touching the code and just increasing the heap size won’t help.

Comment: Garbage collection should work if closed but should likely be set to null - also, we've run into issues before and while it's not totally recommended you might try explicitly calling it after any heave resource usage with `System.gc();`